# CGAL with -std=c++11

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

I have a problem compiling a ROS package with CGAL and "-std=c++11" flag.

Here is a minimal CMakeLists.txt to reproduce the error:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(cgal_cmake_flags)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} " -std=c++11")

find_package(CGAL REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
set(CGAL_DONT_OVERRIDE_CMAKE_FLAGS TRUE CACHE BOOL "Don't override flags")
message(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
include(${CGAL_USE_FILE})
message(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

During the cmake process, this line gets printed:

```
"-- USING CXXFLAGS = '-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -frounding-math; -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG'"
```

You will notice the semi-colon after -frounding-math. This causes big problems when compiling. I tried "catkin_make -DCGAL_DONT_OVERRIDE_CMAKE_FLAGS=TRUE" but it didn't help.

Does someone has experience setting c++11 standard and using CGAL with catkin?

Thanks a lot,
Gaël

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191175/cgal-with--std=c++11/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-25**:
afaik ROS does not support c++11.

**Comment by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on 2014-08-25**:
I didn't know that but I know that I already compiled some of my packages with c++11.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-08-25**:
The current guideline for ROS packages is to not require C++11. It does not prevent packages to build with C++11 if they are aware that this might make them incompatible with platforms which do not support a C++11 compiler yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The semicolon is coming from your line changing the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. Whenever you set a CMake variable with multiple arguments you are not defining a string variable but a list - and list items are separated with a semicolon in CMake.

Therefore you should set the variable with a single value:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on 2014-08-26**:
This solved the issue. I had to correct this in other packages because the fact to include CGAL in one of my packages modifies CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS for all packages even with

set(CGAL_DONT_OVERRIDE_CMAKE_FLAGS TRUE CACHE BOOL "Don't override flags")